# 2000s era novel whose central conceit was Creationism

Tags: story-identification

In the early 2000s, I read a novel, set in the near future, whose central conceit was a "Young Earth/Universe" and whose cosmology resembled a Medieval one more than our own.  The beginning contained a long infodump about how current physics was shown to be false after all.

I could have sworn the author was James Hogan, but the closest (in time) candidate in the boxes is *Echoes of an Alien Sky*, which is nothing like this.   (It does contain an infodump about incorrect Earth science). But I'm sure it's from a science fiction imprint.

The sheer effort of maintaining suspension of disbelief appears to have pushed the other details out.  I recall that some of the characters were some young people and their father on a roadtrip.

Comment: "Prophet of bones" by Kosmatka maybe? That has a lot of exposition about the age of the Earth, but it was published in 2013.

Comment: If it's a Ptolemaic Earth instead of a strictly biblical Earth, it might be [Celestial Matters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_Matters) (1996), but the difference is big enough I hesitate to offer it as an answer.

Comment: If the book featured Nazis and time travel, perhaps *Wayback* by Sam Batterman.

Comment: Hi @Spencer - are any of these suggestions useful?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I'm not ruling your suggestion out, but DavidW's sounds more likely. I have to check boxes to see if either is there.

Comment: I'd throw in one of the "The Science of Discworld" novels by Terry Pratchet? The wizzards of the unseen University create a parallel universe and go exploring (roadtripish). Their Universe is very cliche-medieval  and every 2. chapter explains the difference between real-world and discworld physics and how our science and beliefs of the universe evolved. Father and young people doesn't fit exactly, but Archchancelor and students or subordinates might fit?

Comment: The third one (from 2005) is specifically about Darwin and evolution but I believe all of them touch on evolution/creation.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I'm misremembering _Echoes of an Alien Sky_. If I can pull together something cohesive, I'll post an answer.